# Android - Service - How a Service will be created by Android internally?

Tags: android, service, process

I want to know more about the behaviour of Android and I want to know how a service will be created by Android.

I know the way how to create a service...extend from the Service class and so on...

But the interesting thing is how the service will be created (in code) or how an activity can be bound to the service (method: bindService(..))?

Does anyone know the procedure? Fighting through source code of android was not successfull :/

Answer (score 0):

This code is running in my application

```
import java.io.IOException;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MusicService extends Service {

    private static final String TAG = "MyService";
    public static MediaPlayer mediaplayer;
    String musicfile="http://radio.radioamerica.org:8000/ra.mp3";

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        Log.i(" ibinder ", "");
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
    mediaplayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaplayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        mediaplayer.stop();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid) {

        Log.d(TAG, "onStart");
        if (intent.getExtras().getString("paths") == null) {
            Log.i("Intent Null", "Null");
        } else {
            Log.i("Intent Not Null", "Not Null");
            musicfile = intent.getExtras().getString("paths");
            Log.i("musicfile", "" + musicfile);
            try {
                mediaplayer.reset();
                mediaplayer.setDataSource(musicfile);
                mediaplayer.prepare();
                mediaplayer.start();
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

any more?

Comment: I wrote: " I know the way how to create a service...extend from the Service class and so on..." I want to know more about the internal procedure in android how a service will be created